# AngularJS: Get the root element of current scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way in angular to get the element where the current scope is defined? I have a directive that modifies some stuff based on the current scope but it needs to know where the root element for that scope is.

I know there is a way to get the root element for the entire app but is there a simple way to get it for just the scope you're in?

One way I have thought of doing this is in my link function doing something like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  var scopeRootElement = element.parents('.ng-scope').first();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are attempting to do ? What you are attempting to do seems like a code smell - I have a strong feeling there is a better way to do it than get parent scopes..

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the past there was an `$element` service, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/u52B5bVzdqs).  However, I don't believe it exists anymore since this kind of behaviour really violates the separation of concerns.  I think you should put a class,attribute,etc on the controller element and then look for it via parent inside your directive (using jquery).

So assuming you have jQuery so you can use the `parents` method, your link function could look like this if you wanted to make the element with ng-controller red.  This kind of depends on your implementation and you might consider adding your own class instead of relying on some angular notation:

```
...
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {  
  element.parents('[ng-controller]:eq(0)').css('background-color','red');
  // or element.parents('.mycustomclass').css('background-color', 'red');
 ...
```